# Resolve domain from IP address using Ruby

Tags: ruby, dns, ip

I have requirements to find domain name using IP address using Ruby.

I have some IP addresses. I got every time different random IP address. But I have to filter the IP addresses that have a domain name.

How to find the domain name?

Comment: Can you explain more about what you're trying? (And if you have code, can you show your code?)

Comment: I am finding domain name using ip address. I have no code actually find code or any library to use find domain name of IP address

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the stdlib [Resolve](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/resolv/rdoc/Resolv.html).

> `Resolv` is a thread-aware DNS resolver library written in Ruby. Resolv can handle multiple DNS requests concurrently without blocking the entire Ruby interpreter.
>
> `Resolv` can look up various DNS resources using the DNS module directly.

```
require 'resolv'
Resolv.getname "210.251.121.214" # => "ci.ruby-lang.org"
```

Comment: Its works Thank but some times not display proper domain name..like ip-static.name.net